# Get rid of the formatted text entering field and fallback to textarea

Tags: html, emacs, tactic

Most of the online programming courses have this text area (where you type in the code) in their webpage which gives you code coloring and parenthesis pairing, etc.

The draw back of this is that one can't use tools like [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) in tandem with it.

Making the question more concrete, I currently want to use tools like the one mentioned above with [TACTIC](http://community.southpawtech.com/)'s script editor. The html code behind the text area is something like:

```
<div class="ace_layer ace_text-layer" style="width: auto; padding: 0px 4px;">
   <div style="height:14px" class="ace_line">
     <span class="ace_identifier">ASSET_TASK</span>&nbsp;<span class=
     "ace_keyword ace_operator">=</span>&nbsp;<span class="ace_string">"rig"</span>
   </div>

   <div style="height:14px" class="ace_line">
     <span class="ace_identifier">ASSET_STATUS</span>&nbsp;<span class=
     "ace_keyword ace_operator">=</span>&nbsp;<span class="ace_string">"Approved"</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

and not `<textarea>`.

So what tweaking should I be doing in order to achieve the above mentioned setup?

Comment: Is this related to Emacs...? Having difficulty seeing the reason for the `emacs` tag.

Comment: @SlowLearner Well, not directly. Since I mentioned *It's all text* which is related to Emacs, so it's kind of indirectly related to Emacs, other then that it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If the javascript editor in question doesn't provide some way to disable it, then I would suggest simply using [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) (assuming you use Firefox), to disable that editor (and every other unwanted javascript) by default.